# I have unicode text which has CSS RTL rendering issues

Tags: css

I have unicode text to be rendered in RTL. The theme is LTR. The text in paragraphs renders correctly, but there is an issue that is random as displayed in the image below.

If you change the orientation, or resize the browser, it is corrected.

[image]

```
.AF {
 font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq',MehrNastaliq;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 direction: rtl;
}
```

```
<div dir="rtl" class="AF"><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p></div>
```

Comment: Could you please put your `HTML` and `CSS` here ?

Comment: Looks like a normal RTL paragraph. What is the exact issue here?

Comment: .AF {
    font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq',MehrNastaliq;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    direction: rtl;
}
<div dir="rtl" class="AF"><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p></div>

Comment: @Tanzeel 1) It is best to add information like that by editing your question. I have done it for you this time. 2) Is the page valid HTML according to a markup validator, e.g. [W3C Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)?

Comment: Running the URL in validation service it get, Text run is not in Unicode Normalization Form C warning...

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with [&nbsp], [&rsquo], [&hellip] and etc were present in the content. Once these removed from the content fixed the issue.